# Heat increase after pressure drop in polymer filter

Tags: organic-chemistry, pressure, filtering

I would like to calculate the heat increase in polymer filter. A polymer filter (mesh size p.ex.20 µm) decreases the mass pressure of the polymer flow.

How it works: The polymer is melted in an extruder, this builds up some mass pressure. This pressure is then enhanced by a melt pump to e.g. 150 bar. The polymer is then filtered (seee image below). Thereby the melt pressure drops to e.g. 80 bar. I imagine that there should be a temperature increase in the filter due to the pressure drop.

How can I calculate the temperature increase?

Side info:
When other materials expand (as gas in a refrigerator), the temperature decreases. This is because the intermolecular distance increases. Thereby the atoms potential energy increases. I am just mentioning this to stress that polymer melt is almost incompressible, so this effect is not valid here.

Reference: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/why-do-gases-cool-on-expansion.470311/

[image]